# Using formatter in web flux

Tags: spring-webflux

I am trying to use Formatter in webflux application but its throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iterating over a toIterable() /
>   toStream() is blocking, which is not supported in thread
>   reactor-http-nio-2

Exception indicate i can't use block and method is expecting an object of PetType. I wanted to know if there is any other way to do this

```
@Component
public class PetTypeFormatter implements Formatter<PetType> {

    private final PetTypeService petTypeServive;    

    public PetTypeFormatter(PetTypeService petTypeServive) {
        this.petTypeServive = petTypeServive;
    }

    @Override
    public String print(PetType petType, Locale locale) {
        return petType.getName();
    }


    @Override
    public PetType parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException 
    {


        Iterable<PetType> findPetTypes =    petTypeServive.findAll().toIterable();

        for (PetType type : findPetTypes) 
        {
            if (type.getName().equals(text)) {
                return type;
            }
        }

        throw new ParseException("type not found: " + text, 0);
    }

}
```

Edit:
The method signature of controller which i am using is

```
@PostMapping("/pets/new")
    public String processCreationForm(@ModelAttribute("owner") Owner owner, @Valid Pet pet,BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
```

and the Pet class petType property which i was setting through the custom formatter when using webmvc

Edit2:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Pet
{   
    private String id;
    private PetType petType;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate birthDate; 
    private String name;
}

@Setter
@Getter
public class PetType
{
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how it's used with flux.

Comment: petTypeServive.findAll() is returning FLux<PetType> i tried different techniques i.e. collectList() but when ever i call block its throwing error stated in question , as you can see its expect PetType in return i tried Mono<PetType> but then print is causing issue

Comment: Why are you blocking? Can you post a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implement blocking business logic in a formatter.

The purpose of the `Formatter<T>` interface is to write custom parsing of strings, for example json strings, csv strings etc. and parse these into an object.

What you are doing is making a database call in a formatter, which is **NOT** the purpose of the formatter interface.

Since you have not shown us:

- the purpose of the formatter
- where the formatter is used
- whats in the passed string into the formatter
- what your request looks like
- What a Pet class is
- What a PetType is

I can't help you more than this. You are trying to do a blocking call in a webflux application in an interface that does not allow reactive coding (it returns a concrete value), You need to rethink your solution to the problem.

Please explain what your problem is and what it is you want to do, and not the problem with the code, the problem you are trying to solve, and we might be able to help you more.

Comment: i have added the pet and pet type classes , the request is sending petType as string so i need to convert it into the petType object for that i was calling the database to get the appropriate value in a loop (for this i will chnage the call to get the pet type by id it will return the Mono<PetType> )

Comment: you should take your string, pass it to the database and the database should return one single `Mono<T>` with what you need, then you flatMap the result.

Comment: so instead of passing Pet to controller i have to pass all the fields of pet separately  with pet type as string and then make database call in controller then zip the result

Comment: For learning purpose i was trying to convert petclinic into webflux. You can see the same code here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/owner/PetTypeFormatter.java